# Getting Emacs to choose between LaTeX/ConTeXt mode depending on file?

Tags: emacs, auctex

I have lots of LaTeX files, and my AucTeX has been set up to automatically open up all *.tex files in LaTeX-mode.  But more recently I've started using ConTeXt, and for those files (which also end in .tex) I'd like to use ConTeXt-mode.  Is there any way of embedding something in the file which will tell Emacs to open up the correct mode?

I can start a file with, for example

```
-*- mode: context; -*-
```

which works well, but even if it's the very first line in the file, ConTeXt still parses it and writes it to the output, although it comes way before `\starttext`.

Does anybody have any better suggestions?  I suppose the sensible thing would be to move all ConTeXt files into one directory tree, and set up a `.dir-locals.el` file in that directory, which would tell Emacs to open up all .tex files using ConTeXt mode.  But I'd still like to be able to do it on a file-by-file basis.

FWIW, I'm using Linux.

Thanks!

Comment: By the way: are there really *no* acceptable answers for all the 8 questions you have asked up to now? If there are, please click the *accept* button on the best answer each (it's the checkmark like symbol below the up/down icons).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can't you simply put a `%` in front of this line?

I'm using this in the last some lines of my files, for example.

```
%%% Local Variables: 
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: "spezialisierung"
%%% End:
```

But

```
% -*- mode: context; -*-
```

in the first line should work, too.

Answer (score 14):

As an alternative to manually setting the `mode` file local variable (which is preferred because it does not rely on heuristics), AucTeX automatically recognizes the TeX format! It knows about LaTeX (detected via `\documentclass`), ConTeXt (detected via `\starttext`) and Plain TeX. For example, you can do the following:

1. Create a file `abc.tex`. AucTeX starts in LaTeX mode by default.
2. Enter `\starttext`.
3. Hit `C-c C-n` to force reparsing of the buffer.
4. AucTeX automatically detects that you plan to write a ConTeXt document and switches to ConTeXt mode.
5. Hit `M-x add-file-local-variable RET mode RET RET` to add the mode as a file-local variable. Then the file will always trigger ConTeXt mode even if the auto-recognition fails.

Comment: +1 `C-c C-n` was very helpful. Yours should be the correct answer.